# is_account_group_member vs is_member

Tags: databricks

I can't understand the difference between these two (ChatGPT doesn't make it clear to me either).

```sql
CREATE VIEW patient_phi AS SELECT * FROM patients
WHERE is_account_group_member('healthcare') AND current_user() = patient_id;
```

vs

```sql
CREATE VIEW patient_phi AS SELECT * FROM patients 
WHERE is_member('healthcare') AND current_user() = patient_id;
```

When to use one or other ?

Comment: Maybe the docs and example on [is_member](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/is_member.html) and [is_account_member](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/is_account_group_member.html) might help ? Sorry have not used these functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Databricks you have an account level. This is a layer above all workspaces. On this level you can have groups. The is_account_group_member checks this level. These groups are propogated to the connected workspace. This method is introduced during the release of Unity Catalog.

The older is_member is only checking the local groups in the workspace, but also the propogated groups i believe. This is an older pre-Unity Catalog method.

So the main difference would be is_account_group_member ONLY checks account level. The other does both.

Edit:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/is_account_group_member.html
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/is_member.html

Comment: Hi Ferdyh, what do you mean with "account level" for eample I have a view and I just want to be query by user insider the group "employes" which one should I use, can you please put a example ?

Comment: If you're not using Unity Catalog, you probably want the is_member.

Comment: Databricks added an 'Databricks Account' where you can manage metastores (for Unity catalog), setup SCIM provisioning, and manage all  your Databricks workspaces in your tenant. More info: https://docs.databricks.com/en/administration-guide/index.html